# Failed to highlight a selected item on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a master-details app that has split view screen using Fragments. The master screen is a list containing RecyclerView. Here's the layout XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Page Title" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/page_list"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />                

</LinearLayout>
```

And the item row layout xml is as follows.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/message_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

On the adapter class, I created a variable to hold position of selected item

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
     private int selectedPos;

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
       holder.bind(mData.get(position));
     }

     class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
         }
         public void bind(ListEntity entity) {
           //UI rendering
         }
         @OnClick(R.id.layout_campaign)
         public void onItemClicked(View view) {
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
            selectedPos = getLayoutPosition();
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
         }
}
```

When I click an item on the list, the list item is not highlighted. Looked into quite a few similar posts regarding this issue, but couldn't get it to work. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight when user press on the row, then just use selectors in the background of your row's parent layout.
**row_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_selected="true"
           android:drawable="@color/red" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@color/red" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

put this xml in drawable and set as background of your parent layout.

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How do I keep the default row selector which contains ripple animations and use highlight logic?

Comment: To highlight just put a flag in your row object. If user clicks on the row, mark that flag as true. So now using this variable you can control the background of your row, means if it is true that means it's selected and change the background by your selected colour(in onBind).